# Can't find a usable init.tcl and conflict version tcl

Tags: 18.04, tcl

I just downloaded the linux version of this software (http://inano.au.dk/about/research-centers/nmr/software/simpson/) after unpacking the file I run `sudo bash install.sh` and all the dependencies were installed on my ubuntu 18.04 however when I try to run the test file using `simpson test.in` it gives me the following errors

```
SIMPSON is unable to initialize Tcl interpreter. Is init.tcl on your path?
Error: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
    /usr/share/simpson/tcl8.6 /usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.6 ./lib/tcl8.6 ./lib/tcl8.6 ./library ./library ./tcl8.6.5/library ./tcl8.6.5/library

/usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.6/init.tcl: version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.6.5, need exactly 8.6.8
version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.6.5, need exactly 8.6.8
    while executing
"package require -exact Tcl 8.6.8"
    (file "/usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.6/init.tcl" line 19)
    invoked from within
"source /usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.6/init.tcl"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel #0 [list source $tclfile]"
```

Can anyone help me with this? I guess it should be simple but I'm a noob at this stuff

Comment: I think the issue is that the `simpson` installer is bundled with its own (out of date) versions of `libtcl8.6.so` (among other shared libraries) which conflicts with the "system" version. What I'd suggest is installing ALL of the relevant packages (FFTW, BLAS etc.) from the Ubuntu repos and then commenting out the `TCL_LIBRARY` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` exports in the `<bindir>/simpson` wrapper script - so that the bundled libs are ignored altogether.

Comment: steeldriver can you please give more insights on how to do this? I'm quite noob at this

Comment: Please see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that the `simpson` installer is bundled with its own (out of date) versions of `libtcl8.6.so` (among other shared libraries) which conflicts with the "system" version.

What I'd suggest is installing ALL of the relevant packages (FFTW, BLAS etc.) from the Ubuntu repos and then commenting out the `TCL_LIBRARY` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` exports in the `<bindir>/simpson` wrapper script, where `<bindir>` is the location you supplied to the installer script - so that the bundled libs are ignored altogether.

So for example if `<bindir>` is `~/bin`, then `~/bin/simpson` should look something like

```
#!/bin/sh
#export TCL_LIBRARY=/home/steeldriver/share/tcl8.6
#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/steeldriver/share
/home/steeldriver/share/simpson4.2.1 "$@"
```

Comment: Sorry for such a late response I've tried to install tcltck using `sudo apt install tcl8.6 tk8.6` which installed the correct version 8.6.8 and added 

`#export TCL_LIBRARY=/home/usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.6`

But I guess the packages were installed in a different path which I have no idea where is it, do you know how to find that?

I did `locate init.tcl` which indicated `/home/usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.6/init.tcl` but it seems that is not the correct version

Comment: @user9251343 the `#` characters indicate comments - I'm suggesting you should *comment out* existing lines in the `~/bin/simpson` wrapper script, rather than add lines to it

Comment: Sorry I did not understand that. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I wanted to quickly update this thread with how I solved it:
You were right, SIMPSON comes with its own shared tcl library which is the problem. The file was called `libtcl8.6.so`, which was for me in the folder `/usr/share/simpson`. I simply deleted that file and it worked.